# Extra interpolation in ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I'm trying to plot a 3D surface using ListPointPlot3D and it looks almost right, but for some reason it's trying to connect points that should not connect. I think it's confused because the surface is concave, but I'm not sure how to fix it. It should look like a "Z" with curved edges. Is there a way to tell Mathematica that I don't want to connect these points?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure if there’s an easy way around this, but it should be noted that, in general, concave shapes are difficult to work with as the question of which two points to connect is hard. Finding a convex hull that encompasses all of the points, on the other hand, is much easier, and this tends to be how the 3D plots are drawn by default.

Comment: Your question concerns `ListPlot3D` not `ListPointPlot3D` ?